# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'namespace.class'

Tags: c#, sql

I have a windows form that calls a class(DbPOS) to extract a certain data from SQL, then it will save the data from DbPOS then pass it to product(the object constructor class) then to windows form to show the data in windows form. (THIS IS A REQUIREMENT FOR MY CA, I CANNOT SIMPLY JUST 'SELECT*FROM TABLE' IN THE WINDOWS FORM ITSELF)

So i have a problem in DbPOS,
it has this error that says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'namespace.class' where the
>   namespace.Class is my product class(object constructor)

**DbPOS(part):**

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                        DataRow row;
                        conn.Open();
                        da.Fill(table);
                        int nProducts = table.Rows.Count;
                        products = new product[nProducts];
                        for (int i = 0; i < nProducts; i++)
                        {
                            row = table.Rows[i];
                            pdname = row["name"].ToString();
                            product p = new product(pdname);
                            p.PDname = pdname;
                            products[i] = pdname;
                        //products[i]=pdname; pdname above has the error
                        }
```

**product class:**

```
class product
{
    public string pdname;

    public product()
    {
        pdname = "unknown";
    }
    public product(string pdname)
    {
        this.pdname = pdname;
    }

    public string PDname
    {
        get { return this.pdname; }
        set { this.pdname = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use `products[i] = p;`?

Comment: `products[i]` is an index to the array of `product` classes - you're trying to assign a string to that element, hence the error.  You can only assign an instance of `product` to the elements in that array.

Comment: Jesse, i tried that, it returns literally the string 'namespace.product' to my windows form

Comment: @samuellikestogame: That is your problem. Please show the code where you try to display the `products`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataRow row;
conn.Open();
da.Fill(table);
int nProducts = table.Rows.Count;
products = new product[nProducts];
for (int i = 0; i < nProducts; i++)
{
    row = table.Rows[i];
    pdname = row["name"].ToString();
    product p = new product(pdname);
    p.PDname = pdname;
    products[i] = p;
}
```